# Creation subdomain in home root path

Tags: server, cpanel

When I want to create a sub domain in my cpanel, it goes in:

```
home/public_html/sub domain
```

But I want to create its root path there:

```
home/sub domain
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

add the sub domain as a primary domain from WHM and that should the trick.

by adding it in such way will make you administrate it as a separate account.